# Automaticaly convert empty strings to null in Java using JsonB deserialization

Tags: java, jackson, jsonp, jsonb

did anyone tried to find a good solution to automatically convert all empty strings to null object on deserialization using JsonB (Yasson)?

I encountered this problem on migration from Jackson to Jsonb where empty string value in request produces deserialization exception since it cannot be parsed to object.

HTTP request payload:

```
{
   fieldNameUid: '', // Java property is UUID type
}
```

Jackson had the following configuration:

```
public void customize(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL);

        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(
                String.class,
                new StdDeserializer<>(String.class) {

                    @Override
                    public String deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context)
                            throws IOException {
                        String result = StringDeserializer.instance.deserialize(parser, context);
                        if (result == null || result.isBlank()) {
                            return null;
                        }
                        return result;
                    }
                });
        module.addDeserializer(byte[].class,
                new StdDeserializer<>(byte[].class) {

                    @Override
                    public byte[] deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context)
                            throws IOException {
                        String result = StringDeserializer.instance.deserialize(parser, context);
                        if (result == null || result.isBlank()) {
                            return null;
                        }
                        return result.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    }
                });

        mapper.registerModule(module);
    }
```

and current Jsonb config:

```
public class JsonbObjectMapper implements JsonbConfigCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(JsonbConfig jsonbConfig) {

        jsonbConfig
                .withDeserializers(new StringDeserializer(), new ByteArrayDeserializer(), new EnumDeserializer())
                .withSerializers(new EnumSerializer());

    }

    public static class StringDeserializer implements JsonbDeserializer<String> {

        @Override
        public String deserialize(javax.json.stream.JsonParser jsonParser, javax.json.bind.serializer.DeserializationContext deserializationContext, Type type) {
            final String str = jsonParser.getString();
            return str == null || str.isBlank() ? null : str;
        }
    }

    public static class ByteArrayDeserializer implements JsonbDeserializer<byte[]> {

        @Override
        public byte[] deserialize(javax.json.stream.JsonParser jsonParser, javax.json.bind.serializer.DeserializationContext deserializationContext, Type type) {
            final String str = jsonParser.getString();
            return str == null || str.isBlank() ? null : str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
    }

    public static class EnumDeserializer implements JsonbDeserializer<Enum> {

        @Override
        public Enum deserialize(javax.json.stream.JsonParser jsonParser, javax.json.bind.serializer.DeserializationContext deserializationContext, Type type) {

            final String str = jsonParser.getString();
            if (str == null || str.isBlank()) {
                return null;
            }
            for (final Enum en : ((Class<Enum>) type).getEnumConstants()) {
                if (en.toString().equals(str)) {
                    return en;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class EnumSerializer implements JsonbSerializer<Enum> {

        @Override
        public void serialize(Enum anEnum, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializationContext serializationContext) {
            jsonGenerator.write(anEnum == null ? null : anEnum.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no alternative property for JsonB, I ended up writing custom deserialiser for UUID type.